# Bitwise test in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I hava a following bit string:

```
var input = '11100001';
```

I want to check if eight bit is present, so I have tried with:

```
input & '10000000'
```

but it gives me `8918528`. How should I test it ?

Comment: Why do you use strings? Bitwise operators work on numbers.

Comment: @Bergi I get it from API. Looks like, parsing to int is a solution then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to do a bitwise AND on two strings, which implicitly converts them to integers assuming base 10. You should parse them to integers explicitly supplying the base:

```
parseInt(input,2) & parseInt('10000000',2)
// 128
```

Edit:
to check if `n`-th bit is set you could just shift to right by `n-1` bits and check if it's `1`

```
parseInt(input,2) >> 7 & 1 === 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @pawel's excellent answer, let me explain why you get `8918528`:

As soon as JavaScript sees this:

```
'11100001' & '10000000'
```

it will try to cast the two strings to integers; Integers in base 10 precisely. So we get:

```
11100001 (base10) & 10000000 (base10)
```

which is,

```
101010010101111101100001 (base2) & 100110001001011010000000 (base2)
```

Applying bit-wise AND,

```
101010010101111101100001 &
100110001001011010000000
------------------------
100010000001011000000000 (base2)
```

Which is,

```
8918528 (base10)
```

Comment: Great work with this detailed explanation, thanks :)